# solita/docker-systemd docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i want to use an image in docker-compose with systemctl in it, i saw this image in the internet https://github.com/solita/docker-systemd, it work good , but when i tried to use it with docker-compose it dosnt work(it worket but systemctl dosen't, it give this error "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate." )

```
  test1:
container_name: 'test1'
build: './test'
volumes:
  - /:/host
  - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
security_opt:
  - "seccomp=unconfined"  
tmpfs:
  - /run
  - /run/lock
privileged: true
```

and the build file is test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
if nsenter --mount=/host/proc/1/ns/mnt -- mount | grep /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "The systemd cgroup hierarchy is already mounted at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd."
else
  if [ -d /host/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd ]; then
    echo "The mount point for the systemd cgroup hierarchy already exists at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd."
  else
    echo "Creating the mount point for the systemd cgroup hierarchy at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd."
    mkdir -p /host/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
  fi
  echo "Mounting the systemd cgroup hierarchy."
  nsenter --mount=/host/proc/1/ns/mnt -- mount -t cgroup cgroup -o none,name=systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
fi
echo "Your Docker host is now configured for running systemd containers!"
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using systemd if at all possible.  In particular your Dockerfile has a privileged container with the entire host filesystem mounted; you have almost no isolation from the host at all.  Best practice is to just run your service as a foreground process as the container's default CMD.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run "systemctl" in docker to start/stop services then you could do that without systemd. The [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) is made for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use systemd, you can follow the [repo](https://github.com/SkullDesperados/docker-rockylinux9-systemd) it's for Rockylinux.
However you can use this repo to have systemd enable for [Ubuntu](https://github.com/eniocarboni/docker-ubuntu-systemd)

When you use 'docker run' you need to set like below ((enable rw) and connect to it with docker exec.)

```
`--volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw`
```

You can encounter other problems of compatibilities with systemd in docker (for timedatectl, loginctl etc...) or service command

```
$> dnf install initscripts systemd
$> systemctl start systemd-logind
```

You can after migrate it to docker-compose mode